# How to make a JButton add user input to an ArrayList and display it in a JList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I have an app that contains 3 classes - main gui (Book), add, contact.

I have a JList in my phonebook class.
I have a dialog window as my add class as it needs to add a contact, now I can add the data but storing it into an array and then placing that into a JList is proving tricky.

Would anyone be able to help? I am new to java and I understand that I will need to use defaultListModel at some point but I don't quite understand where

My button in the add class is called btnOK
my arraylist is just ArrayListcontact
my JList is just called list.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem that you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT be using an ArrayList to store the data. The data should be stored in the ListModel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example that shows you how to use the "Hire" button to add a persons name to the list.

Comment: Thankyou for your help Camickr as I have been stuck on this for a while! Hopefully I can get this working now :)